# CodeIgniter 4 me obliga a usar $this->db->table()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

tengo el siguiente problema, no quisiera estar usando a cada rato el "$this->db->table($this->table)->" para poder hacer referencia a la tabla, pero en este codigo si no lo utilizo en mis funciones insertAlmacen y eliminarAlmacen, no me inserta ni elimina, pero en el select me doy cuenta que no me obliga y si me devuelve mis datos con normalidad, paso codigo.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;
use Exception;

class almacenModel extends Model{

protected $table = "almacen";
protected $primaryKey = 'idalmacen'; // Asume que este es el nombre de tu clave primaria.

public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

}
public function insertAlmacen(object $datos){
    
    $this->db->table($this->table)->insert($datos);
    
}
public function selectAlmacen(){
    $this- >select('idalmacen,codigo,descripcion,nombre,categoria,proveedor,fecha_ingreso,cantidad,precio_compra');
    $this->where('estado',1)->orderBy("idalmacen","desc");

    return json_encode($this->get()->getResult());

}
public function eliminarProducto(int $idalmacen){

    $this->where("idalmacen",$idalmacen)->update(["estado"=>0]);
 }   
}
```

y aqui estoy haciendo mis peticiones Ajax

```
    function eliminar(codigo_producto){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>/almacenController/eliminar/"+codigo_producto,
        type: "PUT",
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#myTable").DataTable().ajax.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Lo que mas me interesa es la diferencia entre mis funciones selectAlmacen y eliminarProducto, donde uno no es necesario pasarle "$this->db->table($this->table)" y el otro si tengo que hacerlo para que me pueda funcionar.

Comment: Y, ¿por qué usas `table`? Deberías usar `insert`, tal y como lo haces en la parte del `select`, algo así: **`$this->insert($datos);`**. [Revisa la documentación y los ejemplos de código](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert#inserting-data). Para el `delete`, exactamente lo mismo, aunque tienes un lío en esa parte. ¿Qué quiere decir esto: `$this->where("idalmacen",$idalmacen)->update(["estado"=>0]);`

Comment: Para borrar registros aplicando varios criterios `where`, puedes pasarlo uno a uno, o en un array, [ver la doc sobre `where`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert#where)  y usando el método `delete` directamente [ver la doc sobre delete](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert#deleting-data). Por ejemplo, asumiendo que quieres borrar las filas con criterio igual al valor de `$idalmacen` y `estado=0` sería simplemente esto: `$params=array("idalmacen"=>$idalmacen, "estado"=>0);` y luego: `$this->delete($params);`

Comment: a tu primer comentario, es lo que quier hacer, solo usar insert, pero no me inserta, y cuando le agrego el $this->db->table(), recien me inserta
Sobre el eliminar, es solo poner un estado a 0, porque estoy haciendo un select con estado 1.

Comment: No entiendo realmente. No puedes eliminar y actualizar al mismo tiempo, no tiene sentido,. se borras el registro, ya no lo tendrás disponible para hacer un `update`. A no ser que quieras actualizar un valor en otra tabla, en cuyo caso lo mejor sería programar un TRIGGER a nivel de base de datos.

Comment: No A.Cedano, mi problema era que no queria usar el $this->db->table para asignar una tabla a mis query de codeingiter, pero encontre la solucion, es que me faltaba la variable $allowField algo asi y cuando coloque mis columnas permitidas, recien pude solucionar esa incomodad y ya no era necesario colocar el $this->db->table, tan solo puedo poner el delete, insert o update y listo

Comment: Porqué no usas directamente en el controller la función `insert` que proporciona el modelo directo del framework?, si hace lo mismo que tu función